# stick collections to each other on same level - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

What is the best performing way to get this result. Every millisecond counts. And does someone know what this is called? (80million record hourly job)

```
collection1 = (0, 1, 2)
collection2 = (a, b, c)
collection1 + collection2 = ( [0, a], [1, b], [2, c] )
```

Comment: Are the items in the first collection unique keys?

Comment: @party-ring No. they are the same

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the obvious memory issues this would have then the best non-looping solution would be something like this:

```php
$result = array_map(static function ($data1, $data2) {
    return [$data1, $data2];
}, $dataset1, $dataset2);
```

I ran a small test using two datasets with 1.000.000 entries in each and processed that in about 150ms.

This will scale poorly though, so keep that in mind.

EDIT: This assumes that both collections are of equal length and they have to be mapped one-to-one on the indices.